# when I connect for example 14 points with lines and try to move them its moving very very slow what's making it to move that slow?

Tags: c#

This is the paint event:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            SolidBrush brush;
            Pen p=null;
           Point connectionPointStart;
           Point connectionPointEnd;
           Graphics g = e.Graphics;
           g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
               brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
               p = new Pen(brush);
               for (int idx = 0; idx < wireObject1._point_X.Count; ++idx)
               {
                   Point dPoint = new Point((int)wireObject1._point_X[idx], (int)wireObject1._point_Y[idx]);
                   dPoint.X = dPoint.X - 5; // was - 2
                   dPoint.Y = dPoint.Y - 5; // was - 2
                   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(dPoint, new Size(10, 10));
                   g.FillEllipse(brush, rect);

                  
               }
           
               for (int i = 0; i < wireObject1._connectionstart.Count; i++)
               {

                   int startIndex = wireObject1._connectionstart[i];
                   int endIndex = wireObject1._connectionend[i];

                   

                   connectionPointStart = new Point((int)wireObject1._point_X[startIndex], (int)wireObject1._point_Y[startIndex]);
                   connectionPointEnd = new Point((int)wireObject1._point_X[endIndex], (int)wireObject1._point_Y[endIndex]);
                   p.Width = 4;
                   g.DrawLine(p, connectionPointStart, connectionPointEnd);
                   moveCounter++;
                   textBox1.Text = moveCounter.ToString();
               }
                          
        }
```

On the loop in the bottom I'm running over the _connectionstart List which is type of int.

I added a int variable I called it moveCounter to see how many time its calling this loop and drawing the lines.

If I'm adding two points over the pictureBox1 connect them with one line then drag one of the points around its moving smooth. Same thing with 3 connected points and with 7 connected points but when I'm getting to 9-10 points connected with many lines and try to move it drag it around or any point that is not connected everything is moving very very slow and as much as I add a new connected line between two points its getting slower.

So the problem can be a bug with my loop's in the paint event or that in the move event its doing so many time pictureBox1.refresh();

So I added a timer enabled it true in the designer and set it to 30 milliseconds. In the move event I raise a flag and in the timer tick event I check if the flag is on I make a pictureBox1.refresh(); and reset back the flag. The idea is that when I move the points or the connected points it will do it each 30 milliseconds.

But it didn't solve the problem. Still when I have 9-10 points connected with many lines between them everything is getting very slow.

This is the picturebox1 mouse move event:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (mouseMove == true)
            {
                mouseDrag = true;
                Point NewPoint = e.Location;
                                  wireObject1.MovePoint(selectedIndex, NewPoint, NewPoint); // when moving a point dragging the other point is vanished deleted. To check why !

                    label1.Text = "{X = " + NewPoint.X + "}" + " " + "{Y = " + NewPoint.Y + "}";
                    refreshFlag = true;
                    timer2.Start();
                

            }
            else
            {
                label19.Text = "{X = " + e.X + "}" + " " + "{Y = " + e.Y + "}";
            }
        }
```

timer2 is another timer I added just to see how many times it moved in 5 seconds. So if timer1 set to 30 milliseconds I should see after 5 seconds something about 150 moves.

So in timer1 tick event I did:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (refreshFlag == true)
            {
                pictureBox1.Refresh();
                refreshFlag = false;
            }
        }
```

I was sure the timer1 idea should solve the problem but it didn't. So I wonder where the problem is maybe i did something wrong with the loop's in the paint event ?

The List _connectionstart contain indexes for example if I have two points connected with one line and I clicked on one point and drag this point around which make the line the be longer or shorter then in _connectionstart for example I have one place/cell [0] which contain index 0

In the List _point_X I have for example now two cells place in [0] 120.0 and in [1] 180.0 which are the points coordinates same for the _point_Y List.

Now the question is where is the problem ? A bug in the paint event ? Something with the move event ? I can't figure out why its getting so slow when it have 9-10 points connecting with a lot of lines between them.

For example I tested now with two points connected with a line I moved one point around which stretch the line longer or shorter and after 5 seconds the result was 160 moves counted then after another 5 seconds it was 323 and so on. So it seems to be working the timer1 and the 30 milliseconds or I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First, a few tweaks for the application: 
Did You try to run the logic separated from drawing? => For example, an "updateData()" method and a "draw()" method? Also I would recommend to use the [DoubleBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered.aspx).

Second, if the performance is bad for a larger set of data (when You add more points), than Your algorithm is not efficient enough. If drawing a polygon is what You want, first update the vertex coordinates and then call [Graphics.DrawPolygon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd0c4s09.aspx)